# PHP Sub-query to select all user's profile who are friends with me in Friends table

Tags: php, mysql

I did few hours of research before posting a question here and had no luck.
Let's start with examples in the table so it is easy for you to understand what I am trying to do:

In the profile table I have profiles registered and their profile_id is:
john123
joee
smith
hassey

The above profiles are friends with each other and the friends table consist of two attributes which are profile_one and profile two. Following is how they are friends with eachother:

john123 friends with joee 
john123 friends with Smith
john123 friends with hassey

hassey friends with joee
hassey friends with smith

When I try to fetch whoever is friends with currently logged in user, it works fine and returns true  using the following query:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT profile_one, profile_two 
                           FROM friendsTbl
                           WHERE profile_one = '{$this->myID}' OR profile_two = '{$this->myID}'")
```

Now I want to fetch these users profile information also so that I can display their first and last name and thus I used sub-query which is as following, however it returns false and I get the error which is Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object. That error displays on the line where I have used while loop. Sub-query:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT profile_id FROM profileTbl
                           WHERE profile_id IN (SELECT profile_one, profile_two 
                           FROM friendsTbl
                           WHERE profile_one = '{$this->myID}' OR profile_two = '{$this->myID}')");
```

The above returns false and fatal error as stated above.
I would really appreciate your help with this as I have been trying to do it for a day or so without any luck.

Note: I am using classes and functions for this project therefore it is object oriented.

---

@John, after your amendments to the query. The following is what is being output:
Notice: Undefined index: profile_one on line 609  <-- Code on this line is $profile_one = $profiles['profile_one'] inside foreach($profile as $profiles) 
 
Notice: Undefined index: profile_one on line 610 <-- Code on this line is $profile_one = $profiles['profile_two'] inside foreach($profile as $profiles) 

Following is the friends table

```
+-------+-----------+------------+
|   id  |profile_one| profile_two|
+-------+-----------+------------+
|   33  | john123   |  hassey    |
|   34  | john123   |  smith     |
|   35  | joee      |  john123   |
+-------+-----------+------------+
```

following is the profiles table:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
| u_id  |   f_name  |   l_name  |     profile_id    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|  23   |   john    |    larr   |   john123         |
|  26   |   joee    |    attwo  |   joee            |
|  27   |   smith   |    Mark   |   smith           |
|  28   |   hassey  |    Mess   |   hassey          |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Now what I expect the result to be is whichever user is logged in which is by passing $this->myid that contains user session ID, it'll be display those friends to those users that they are friends with. This worked in original sql statement that I posted at first however now I also would like the friends f_name and l_name to display which matches the profile_id in profile table to profile_one or profile_two in friends table.

Comment: james if you could read [MY POST](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2733506) about how to ask a proper mysql question it will make it so I can edit / test my answer and make sure it solves your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a reason for you to be using sub-queries. If something can be done with a sub-query, there's a big chance you can do it with a `JOIN`. If that's possible, using a `JOIN` is a better solution and usually faster.

Try using a similar query:

```
SELECT 
    friendsTbl.*,
    profileTbl.*
FROM friendsTbl
LEFT JOIN profileTbl ON (profile_name = IF(friendsTbl.profile_one = 'john123',friendsTbl.profile_two, friendsTbl.profile_one) )
WHERE friendsTbl.profile_one = 'john123' OR friendsTbl.profile_two = 'john123'
```

Here is an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0ca8f/2), which shows all friends of the user `john123`

Comment: Thanks but the above code only works if I replace 1 with 0 for
WHERE friendsTbl.profile_one = 1 OR friendsTbl.profile_two = 1

And also the foreach loop is not getting those users profile information but my own information instead as I saw in the debugging. It does display the users that I am friends with though but isn't getting their information. It would be great if it did cause that's exactly what I want.

Comment: I'm petty sure it works, i tested it on a test db. I'll add a sqlfiddle in a moment.

Comment: Here's the sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0ca8f/2. Apparently I've forgotten to replace a column in the query, therefore it was not working right.

Comment: I've replaced it with $this->myID and it works perfectly :)
Thanks a lot

Comment: Is it possible to also output the first and last name of both of the user? The first and last name of John123 user?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Take a look at this example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0ca8f/9. The initials `up_*` and `fp_*` mean `user_profile` and `friend_profile` and are there for easier code reading. `user_profile` is the current user i.e. `john123` and `friend_profile` is the friend i.e. `joee`.

Comment: Wonderful, you're a great person. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I have one more question related to a similar query if you will be able to answer. Please have a look here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a10f39/1

What I'm trying to do is show all the post made by john123 on his own profile and post that he made on his friend's profile and also show all the post that his friends made on their own profile and post that his friends made on john123's profile. I can open a question for this if you like to give you vote if you prefer that :) Thanks

Comment: It would be better if you'd open a new question. Although it's related to this query, it's something different from the initial question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have opened the new question and here is the link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944042/news-feed-in-php-mysql-display-my-own-post-as-well-as-post-made-by-my-own-frien

Answer (score 1):

you cannot select two things in your sub query

```
SELECT profile_id FROM profileTbl
WHERE profile_id IN (SELECT profile_one, profile_two # issue here
FROM friendsTbl
WHERE profile_one = '{$this->myID}' OR profile_two = '{$this->myID}')
```

you are basically saying where id = 1 , 2 where 1 and 2 are columns

you can try a `CASE` statement

```
SELECT profile_id 
FROM profileTbl
WHERE profile_id IN 
(   SELECT 
        CASE WHEN profile_one = '{$this->myID}' THEN profile_one
             WHEN profile_two = '{$this->myID}' THEN profile_two 
        END
FROM friendsTbl
)
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Thanks John, at least I am getting a different output, it returns true as I see using the var dumb($query). I am getting error, undefined index: friend_one and also for friend_two. Also, it now says I have 1 friend instead of 2 so I debugged the while loop, the while loop selects only one field of the first row and skips the rest. The while loops is

while ($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
       $result[] = $row;
}

Comment: @JamesSmith can you execute the query by itself... as in not in php but like in phpmyadmin or mysql workbench?

Comment: I tried and it is only displaying john123 as a result if I replace that with  $this->myID as this is the user_session. It isn't displaying users that are friends with john123 who are joee, smith and hassey instead.

Comment: @JamesSmith ok can you post some relevant data for me to look at? i have a post [HERE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2733506) on what should be in a question and some really helpful tips if you can take a look at it and get back to me with some more relevant information I can help you.. it has something do to with the WHERE clause but I have to know what the data is to help further

Comment: @JamesSmith what is in $this->myID?

Comment: @JamesSmith also this query works fine so its probably something with your php code http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88d5e/4

Comment: I am storing the user session in the $this->myID variable. Yes, that is the exact result I am getting if I run the query in the phpmyadmin sql.

Comment: @JamesSmith well sounds like you need to debug the php code.. the query returns what you want it to :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your schema. In the n-n relationship table, where you're storing the friendships (`friendsTbl`), you should be enforcing a UNIQUE composite index on the two columns and making each column specific to a part of the relationship.  That way you can treat the first column profile_one (and rename it) as `profile` and the second column as `friends_with`. So, then to get who you are friends with:

```
SELECT friends_with
FROM FriendsTbl
WHERE profile = {your_profile_id}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex but there comes a problem. What happens is for example if I add a friend, my user ID will get stored into attribute column and that friend's user ID in profile_two attribute but if they add me then other way round happens and I'm an intermediate to PHP and don't really know how can I force my ID to be stored in profile attribute and friends ID into the friends_with attribute. Any keyword suggestions that I can Google to look up? or any links that you can provide me?