# How to select posts created by me or my friends in a news feed?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to do this for quite a while now and then I figured that it is the SQL query that I cannot get it working properly in the first place.

I am trying to create a simple news feed page similar to Facebook where you can see the post you made on your profile as well as your friends profile and also you can see posts which your friends made on your profile as well as their own profile.

```
SELECT 
    friendsTbl.profile_one,
    friendsTbl.profile_two,
    user_profile.u_id as my_uid,
    user_profile.f_name as my_fname,
    user_profile.l_name as my_lname,
    friend_profile.u_id as friend_uid,
    friend_profile.f_name as friend_fname,
    friend_profile.l_name as friend_lname,
    profilePostTbl.post as post,
    profilePostTbl.post_to as posted_profile,
    profilePostTbl.post_by as posted_by
FROM friendsTbl
LEFT JOIN profileTbl AS user_profile ON user_profile.profile_name = IF(friendsTbl.profile_one = 'john123', friendsTbl.profile_one, friendsTbl.profile_two)
LEFT JOIN profileTbl AS friend_profile ON friend_profile.profile_name = IF(friendsTbl.profile_one = 'john123', friendsTbl.profile_two, friendsTbl.profile_one)
LEFT JOIN profilePostTbl ON (post_by = IF(profilePostTbl.post_to = friendsTbl.profile_one,profilePostTbl.post_to, profilePostTbl.post_by))
WHERE friendsTbl.profile_one = 'john123' OR friendsTbl.profile_two = 'john123'
```

Here's a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a10f39/1

For this example, john123 is the user that is currently logged in and is friends with hassey, smith and joee and therefore only those posts must show in the news feed which john123 posted on his own or his friend's post and the ones that his friends posted on their own profile as well as on john123's profile.

This question is a follow-up to [PHP Sub-query to select all user's profile who are friends with me in Friends table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788864/php-sub-query-to-select-all-users-profile-who-are-friends-with-me-in-friends-ta).

Comment: What do the `IF` statements in the `WHERE` clause do?

Comment: It looks like you are mixing who is friends with who together with what is talking to who, which is why posts end up repeated in your fiddle results. Maybe you need to do the two things separately?

Comment: IF statements basically checks if they are friends or not. It lists out all the friends of john123 and after listing that out, I was trying to output all the post made by john123 itself and whoever is friends with john123 if that makes sense :)

Comment: `profileTbl AS user_profile` - this is an interesting pattern. your tables names are worse than aliases, which means you can improve them. I know it is irrelevant, just saying.

Comment: user_profile is to fetch all the data of the currently logged in user and friend_profile is to fetch all the data of the friend's profile so that I can output who posted on who's profile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but I was half-way writing this so I decided to post it anyway.

I'm going to go a little bit back before hopefully answering your question. When developing applications and constructing databases, you should ***ALWAYS*** try to structure things as descriptive and compact as possible. It would be really awkward to have a variable/column named `color` and store encrypted user passwords there (weird, right?). There are some standard database naming conventions which, when followed, make life a lot easier specially when developing complicated applications. I would advice you to read some blogs regarding the naming conventions. A good starting point may be [this](https://launchbylunch.com/posts/2014/Feb/16/sql-naming-conventions/#why-naming-conventions-are-important) one.

I fully realize that with the suggested changes below you might need to partially/fully rewrite the application code you've written so far, but it's up to you if you really want things working better.

Let's begin by fixing the database structure. By the looks of it, you're doing an application similar to facebook's newsfeed. In this case, using `FOREIGN KEYS` is pretty much mandatory so you could guarantee some data consistency. The example database schema below shows how you can achieve that.

```
-- Application users are stored here.
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id      INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name   VARCHAR(255),
  last_name    VARCHAR(255),
  profile_name VARCHAR(255)
) ENGINE=InnoDb;

-- User friendship relations go here
CREATE TABLE friends (
  friend_id   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  profile_one INT NOT NULL,
  profile_two INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (profile_one) REFERENCES users (user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (profile_two) REFERENCES users (user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDb;

-- User status updates go here
-- This is what will be displayed on the "newsfeed"
CREATE TABLE statuses (
  status_id    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  author_id    INT NOT NULL,
  recipient_id INT NOT NULL,
  message      TEXT,
  -- created date ?
  -- last updated date ?
  FOREIGN KEY (author_id)    REFERENCES users (user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (recipient_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDb;

-- Replies to user statuses go here. (facebook style..)
-- This will be displayed as the response of a user to a certain status
-- regardless of the status's author.
CREATE TABLE replies (
  reply_id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  status_id INT NOT NULL,
  author_id INT NOT NULL,
  message   TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY (status_id) REFERENCES statuses (status_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES users    (user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

Now that this is fixed, we could proceed with the next step - selecting the newsfeed for `john123` (who has `user_id=1`). This can be achieved with the query below:

```
SET @search_id:=1; -- this variable contains the currently logged in user_id so that we don't need to replace the value more than once in the whole query.

SELECT 
    statuses.*,
    author.first_name     AS author_first_name,
    author.last_name      AS author_last_name,
    recipient.first_name  AS recipient_first_name,
    recipient.last_name   AS recipient_last_name
FROM statuses
JOIN users AS author      ON author.user_id    = statuses.author_id
JOIN users AS recipient   ON recipient.user_id = statuses.recipient_id
WHERE (statuses.author_id = @search_id OR statuses.recipient_id = @search_id)
ORDER BY status_id ASC
```

And [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc244/1) you could see it in action in an sqlfiddle. As you can see, just by structuring the database better, I've eliminated the need of a sub-query (which is what `EXISTS / NOT EXISTS` do according to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) and `EXPLAIN`). Furthermore the above SQL code would be a lot easier to maintain and extend.

Anyway, I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. My next aim was to do post reply function so its great that you provided what the table must contain. I will definitely follow your advice and try the mentioned query. I really like your informative answer so +1 for you :)
I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to start with your posts and use EXISTS to limit result to the relevant ones:

```
SELECT * FROM
profilePostTbl post
WHERE 
 -- This post is by a friend of current user or his own post.
 EXISTS (SELECT * FROM friendsTbl WHERE 
         post.post_by IN (profile_one, profile_two)
         AND 'john123' IN (profile_one, profile_two))
 -- This post is addressing the current user
 OR post_to = 'john123';
```

If you want to render names of post authors and addressees, just join them to the post:

```
SELECT post.*,   
    post_by.u_id as by_uid,
    post_by.f_name as by_fname,
    post_by.l_name as by_lname,
    post_to.u_id as to_uid,
    post_to.f_name as to_fname,
    post_to.l_name as to_lname
FROM
  profilePostTbl post INNER JOIN 
  profileTbl post_by ON post.post_by = post_by.profile_name INNER JOIN
  profileTbl post_to ON post.post_to = post_to.profile_name 
WHERE 
 -- This post is by a friend of current user or his own post.
 EXISTS (SELECT * FROM friendsTbl WHERE 
         post.post_by IN (profile_one, profile_two)
         AND 'john123' IN (profile_one, profile_two))
 -- This post is addressing the current user
 OR post_to = 'john123';
```

Comment: Nice one but how can I also display john123's names and the names of other users john123 is friends with that posted with this query?

Comment: It displays the names of the current user which is john123 but doesn't display the names of the other users that he is friends with such a hassey on record one. I tried but it displays the same details without any additional columns.

Comment: If you are testing in SqlFiddle you need to alias column names, as it does not show columns with duplicate name. See the answer updated.